# Javascript "if and else" statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `Terms of Service` page and I want to enforce the user to check the `Checkbox` before clicking the accept button. Otherwise it should show a popup message saying

**please read the ToS before continuing**

and if it's checked and by clicking the accept button they will redirected to the official site.

can anyone help me?

Comment: What you've done? Anything for us?

Comment: We'll need to see what you have so far

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this (unless you care about older browsers) `<input type="checkbox" name="accept_tos" required title="Please read and accept the Terms of Service" />`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<SCRIPT>

//Accept terms & conditions script (by InsightEye www.insighteye.com)
//Visit JavaScript Kit (http://javascriptkit.com) for this script & more.

function checkCheckBox(f) {
  if (f.agree.checked == false ) {
    alert('Please check the box to continue.');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
</SCRIPT>

<form action="/yourscript.cgi-or-your-page.html" method="GET"
 onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">

  <!--Enter your form contents here-->
  <b>By submitting, I agree that all info entered was done
     accurately & truthfully.</b><br>
     I accept: <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="agree">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
  <input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="document.location.href='/index.html';">
</form>
```

or this:

```
<form name="frm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="apply()">If you click this the specified
   url will open.
  <div align=center>&copy<a href="http://www.mine.com" style="color:#3D366F;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;font-size=13px">hscripts.com</a></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function apply() {
   if(document.frm.chk.checked==true) {
     window.open("http://www.mine.com/license/license.html");
   }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Neither of these are particularly "secure". In the first case, if javascript is disabled, the form will submit so there must be a check at the server to determine whether the checkbox was checked or not. In the second case, the user can simply copy the href to get to the page. In both cases, once the user has reached the link, what is to stop them visiting the URL directly in future?

Comment: if you hav solution.plz provide.

Answer (score 0):

Check this `condition` in `submit handler`.

```
if (formname.checkboxname.checked == true)
   {
      //showalert

      return false;
   }else{

     //open your page
  }
```

Comment: That's easier to understand thanks

Comment: cheers :)Mark as answer if you found useful.